# Laravel - Conditional not working on blade

Tags: laravel

this problem is killing my head and I can not get a solution

Laravel version: 5.5.47

I have the most simple if statement:

```
@foreach($order->ship as $os)
  @if($os->destination_info != 0)
    {{ $os->destination_info }}
  @endif
@endforeach
```

For some reason this does not print anything. I have tried all the options. If I just print the variable without the `@if` it gives me Barcelona-Spain so the the conditional is correct it should print

This is my $order->ship:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ship_id] => 92
                    [order_id] => 593
                    [origin_id] => 11
                    [origin_info] => Shenzhen - China
                    [destination_id] => 22
                    [destination_info] => Barcelona - Spain
                    [cbm] => 3.4151
                    [container] => C
                    [container_load_date] => 1566489600
                    [container_arrival_date] => 1567180800
                    [container_number] => 10009000
                    [price] => 53.5
                    [status] => 1
                    [time] => 1565842730
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ship_id] => 93
                    [order_id] => 593
                    [origin_id] => 15
                    [origin_info] => Guangzhou - China
                    [destination_id] => 22
                    [destination_info] => Barcelona - Spain
                    [cbm] => 4.736
                    [container] => C
                    [container_load_date] => 1566489600
                    [container_arrival_date] => 1566576000
                    [container_number] => 10009000
                    [price] => 52.85
                    [status] => 1
                    [time] => 1565842730
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: `$os->destination_info` maybe null

Comment: no, destination_info prints Barcelona-Spain is not null

Comment: So, why you don't simply check `@if($os->destination_info)`

Comment: this is a result from a database query... the variable is always set, and the possible values are 0 or a destination info... but the conditional does not work and I can not understand why

Comment: can you show $order->ship json or array result of your database

Comment: @pal added, please check

Comment: In your case. Please just try `@if($os->destination_info)` instead `@if($os->destination_info !=0 )`

Comment: @TruongDang ok I can try that, but why this "if" does not work?  :(

Answer (score 1):

As per your array representation, `destination_info` is a string and you are comparing it as a number. you can try using `isset` or `is_null` function with a not operator. it will help you

```
@foreach($order->ship as $os)
  @if(!is_null($os->destination_info))
    {{ $os->destination_info }}
  @endif
@endforeach
```

You can use PHP `isset`

```
@foreach($order->ship as $os)
      @if(isset($os->destination_info))
        {{ $os->destination_info }}
      @endif
@endforeach
```

You can read more about [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [`is_null`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) from php official document.

Comment: destination_info will be always set, as it is a result from the database... besides that it will never be null.... it can be 0 or be an string

Comment: Zero as a string or numeric zero, I mean 0 or '0'.

Comment: it is an string string(1) "0"

Comment: In that case, you need to update your code `$os->destination_info != "0"` and check it.